# how to use Pool for multiple sets of processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two sets of parallel operations one follow another, something like this:

```
for i in range(A):
    pool.apply_async(func_a, (params_for_a))


for i in range(B):
    pool.apply_async(func_b, (params_for_b))
```

I have to wait all the func_a processes finished before starting func_b processes. To use join(), I have too close() the pool and then create another pool for func_b. Is creating two pools the only way for this?

What's the difference's between Pool and Process?
What's the difference's between apply_async and map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with the [`AsyncResult`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) object that `apply_async` gives you.  Typically, append them all to a `list`, then do something with them.

```
results = []

for i in range(A):
    results.append(pool.apply_async(func_a, (params_for_a)))

for res in results:
    # block main thread until all results are in
    res.wait() #or do something with res.get()

#all results in, proceed with pool B
```